# ubuntu Wubi SSD Windows 7 - New Linux instalation

Tags: installation, dual-boot, partitioning, wubi, ssd

My system:

CPU: Intel i7
Windows 7
16 GB Ram
Disks:
1 TB HDD - Partitioned for Windows
240 GB SSD primary Windows disk
40 GB SSD - not in use - I thought I would install Ubuntu here.
2 TB HDD New Backup Disk for Windows and Linux?

I want to put Linux on my 40 GB SSD and have it backup to a partition on the 2 TB HDD. I use Acronis to perform automatic backups. I think I will make my Linux partitions Ext4?

Should I use Wubi? I'm not sure if I need it.

Does anyone have a similar system? I would like to make some good decisions now, so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

No, Wubi is designed to try out Ubuntu without partitioning and runs a 'virtual disk'. If you have a 40 GB SSD, then you should install direct, not with Wubi.

Comment: I guess I can't run both Windows and Ubuntu at once unless I use a virtual box, in which case I get decreased performance from the OS that is inside the box?

Comment: @TimAitch right, you need a VM to run both at the same time; neither Wubi nor a normal dual boot will give you this. VM's aren't too bad performance-wise, especially with 16GB Ram, but it's not going to be as fast (especially graphics intensive applications).

Answer (score 0):

You can just boot from the installation USB/DVD and install Ubuntu straight on to you SSD.

The format of the partition that `/` is on is ext4. But Ubuntu should deal with formatting and partitioning if you select "Use entire disk" and the select you 40GB SSD.